# Will including spring inside the swivel hooks used in duffel/messanger bags help?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, springs

so my question is, if a swivel hook used in duffel bags has spring inside for compression, then would it help to reduce the weight on our shoulders when we are running around airport with bag hung on our shoulders either sideways or crossed. See attached image for clarification.[image]

Comment: I don't think it ever will. The item highlighted looks like a clasp to enable the end of the shoulder strap to be attached & removed from the bag. I would be very surprised if it was designed to be a weight relieving device.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't change the weight or mass of the bag, it may help absorb the shock of it landing on your shoulder as you move.

Comment: I phrashed my question incorrectly. i intended to ask if it will help in absorbing the shock on the shoulders as we move. Thank you for the answer